# apollo-client does not work with CORS

Tags: lambda, cors, apollo-client

I am writing a graphql server component on AWS Lambda (NOT using graphql-server).  On the client side I'm using apollo-client.  On the response of the lambda function I'm setting

```
const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" // Required for CORS support to work
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        result: 'mock data',
        input: event,
    }),
};
callback(null, response);
```

On the client side using ApolloClient I get the following error

**Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.**

However when I execute the same request using something like axios then it works fine.  Furthermore when I just execute the request over something like postman I see the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" setting enabled on the response.  Is this a known issue with apollo-client and how do I fix this?

Comment: No, this is more likely an issue of you not being aware what a _preflight_ request is ... For what HTTP method(s) did specify that response you have shown?

Answer (score 42):

To workaround the CORS issue with Apollo you have to pass the `no-cors` option to the underlying `fetch`.

```js
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "your client uri goes here",
  fetchOptions: {
    mode: 'no-cors',
  },
});
```

This is not a specific Apollo problem, rather a configuration that is meant to be tackled on the `fetch` side, see this for more information: https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-the-fetch-api#cross-origin_requests

I wonder why it does works with Axios for you, I'd expect you to have the `no-cors` mode set somewhere.

Comment: I used mode: no-cors and it's silently stops my http headers. Is worth to mentiond that as a side effect of using no-cors

Comment: This option is not available in apollo 3.0

Comment: If i add `mode:'no-cors'` I am getting server side error with response code 500 I dont know how to resolve it

Comment: For Apollo 3.x you put the `fetchOptions` in the `ApolloLink` options

Comment: @adityakumar the reason of error 500 is request header "Content-Type" is set "text/plan;charset=utf-8", and it should be "application/json". I am still finding solution.
Please help if you found already.

Comment: not working damn

Answer (score 10):

[Ivan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51388077/9191712) is correct for Apollo client 2.x.x.

For Apollo client >= 3.0.0 you can use:

```js
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink } from '@apollo/client';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({
      uri: 'your client uri goes here',
      fetchOptions: {
        mode: 'no-cors'
      }
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd assume you're using the AWS API Gateway.

One question for you is: have you enabled CORS for your gateway?
[See how](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html)

I believe that should solve your issues, if you're also sending cookies, you can also set the `"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true` header as well.
  `

Comment: I have enabled CORS in the API gateway as well.  Plus when I do a simple Axios command from the same client app to the same endpoint it works fine.  Its just when I try to go through apollo-client it fails.

Answer (score 1):

the first, fault we are doing is
importing ApolloClient from '**apollo-boost**'. Actually we have to import **ApolloClient** from '**apollo-client**'.

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';
```

Because, **ApolloClient** from **apollo-boost** only supports a smaller subset of configuration options. **ApolloClient** from **apollo-client** gives you all the configuration options.

then we can provide **link** and **cache** only to Apollo-client instance

```
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';

const client = new ApolloClient({ 
    link: new createHttpLink(
        {
            uri: "Your QraphQL Link"
        }
    ),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone still need it, I solved it using this

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-http/#dynamic-uri

I customized my useQuery fetch like this

```
const customFetch = (uri: string, options: any) => {
  const parsed = JSON.parse(options.body)["query"]
  return fetch(
    "https://your-url/",
    {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ query: parsed })
    }
  );
};
const link = new HttpLink({ fetch: customFetch });

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

I am using aws ApiGateway and my useQuery request was not working, but normal fetch did. This was my solution

Answer (score 0):

here is a working example. the server must have CORS enabled. that means the origin of your http request

> origin: https://example.com

must match the access-control-allow-origin header of the response to your request.

> access-control-allow-origin: https://example.com

Then on the Angular client you can use this module:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {ApolloModule, APOLLO_OPTIONS} from 'apollo-angular';
import {HttpLinkModule, HttpLink} from 'apollo-angular-link-http';
import {InMemoryCache} from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import {environment} from 'src/environments/environment';
import {errorLink} from './dm-core/graphql/apollo-link-error';
import {concat} from 'apollo-link';

export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink) {
    return {
        link: concat(errorLink, httpLink.create({uri: environment.graphql, withCredentials: true})),
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
        defaultOptions: {
            watchQuery: {
                errorPolicy: 'all'
            }
        }
    };
}

@NgModule({
    exports: [ApolloModule, HttpLinkModule],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
            useFactory: createApollo,
            deps: [HttpLink]
        }
    ]
})
export class GraphQLModule {}
```

Note the "withCredentials: true":

> ```
>     link: concat(errorLink, httpLink.create({uri: environment.graphql, withCredentials: true})),
> ```

Comment: How do you change the origin from example.com to anything else?

Comment: the origin is sent up by the client to the server. The server just receives it in the origin header and echos it back to the client in access-control-allow-origin header.